# Jinja2 check if lsit empty

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Below is my sample variqable

Sample input for my list is
vars.yml

```
my_list
  - { studInfo: [], studName: "Jack" }
  - { studInfo: [{'name':'John','id','123'},{'name':'Jack','id','112'}], studName: "Aaron" }
```

Can I know how to see whether the list is emptyI tried below i get 2

student.xml.j2

```
list length is {{ item.studInfo|trim|length }}
```

My playbook as below

```
- template:
    src: "{{ role_path }}/tasks/student..xml.j2"
    dest: "{{path }}/{{ item.studName }}.xml"
  loop: "{{ my_list}}"
```

Output expection
Jack.xml

```
list length is 0
```

Aaron.xml

```
list length is 2
```

Comment: Write your playbook.

Comment: I added my playbook

Comment: the reasons i want check list empty or not is to use it in if statement later

Comment: You example vars are not valid yaml nor json. You are not providing a playbook but a task. The task uses a template that you are not showing entirely.. You are not describing the expected result.  If you get as a result `2` on the length of list on the second item, that seems absolutely what is expected. Please read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [providing a minimal reproducible verifiable example](/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi the playybook call the task. I have shown vars.yml, student.xml.j2 and the output file. I will update the expected rewsult

Comment: Please let me know is the details sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are pretty much there, but you do not really spell out in your question what the actual issue is. Whilst your `my_list` var is 'technically' valid, it hurts my eyes so I have converted it into pure, conventional YAML in my example below :) (I tested using your exact syntax as well to confirm that was not introducing any issues)

I think your fundamental issue, is the use of `trim`. This filter expects a string, not a list, and as such does not make sense here. Check out this example playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    my_list:
      - studInfo: [] 
        studName: Jack
      - studInfo:
        - name: John
          id: 123
        - name: Jack
          id: 112
        studName: Aaron
  tasks:
    - name: Outputting string showing the count
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.studName }} list length is {{ item.studInfo | length }}"
      loop: "{{ my_list }}"
    
    - name: Returning a boolean based on whether empty or not
      debug:
        var: item.studInfo | length | ternary(true, false)
      loop: "{{ my_list }}"
```

and here is the output that produces:

```json
PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Outputting string showing the count] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'studInfo': [], 'studName': 'Jack'}) => {
    "msg": "Jack list length is 0"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'studInfo': [{'name': 'John', 'id': 123}, {'name': 'Jack', 'id': 112}], 'studName': 'Aaron'}) => {
    "msg": "Aaron list length is 2"
}

TASK [Returning a boolean based on whether empty or not] ********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'studInfo': [], 'studName': 'Jack'}) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "studInfo": [],
        "studName": "Jack"
    },
    "item.studInfo | length | ternary(true, false)": false
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'studInfo': [{'name': 'John', 'id': 123}, {'name': 'Jack', 'id': 112}], 'studName': 'Aaron'}) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "studInfo": [
            {
                "id": 123,
                "name": "John"
            },
            {
                "id": 112,
                "name": "Jack"
            }
        ],
        "studName": "Aaron"
    },
    "item.studInfo | length | ternary(true, false)": true
}
```